# adding links into javascript

Tags: javascript

I was trying to add links into javascript but could not do it. Loober is checking an input box. According to the focus, i wanted to change the links that appear on the page. changeME is default.

```
      <script type = "text/javascript">


    var check = document.getElementById("loober");
    var testElement = document.getElementById("changeMe");
    var text = "bbb";
    var text2 = "aaa";

             check.onfocus= function()
           {
            testElement.innerHTML = text.link("index.php");
        }
          check.onblur = function()
         {
    testElement.innerHTML = text2.link("home.php");
}



</script>
```

Thanks

Comment: It works here: http://jsfiddle.net/dKH2X/ .  What is the behavior you are observing?

Comment: yes, it shows the links but when i click it says no permission to access this page

Comment: What is the directory structure of index.php compared to the page you've shown us?

Comment: oh, ok.Solved now,thanks a lot:)

Comment: But, i now recognized another problem.I could not click "text". Because when i click it, it loses focus and the blur works.So it disappears.How can i click it?:(

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I asked many sorry:(.I want to display 2 links that appear according to the focus of the input,seperately.But now, one of them is not pressable because this link is there when the input is clicked. But, when a user tries to click that link, it means that input is not clicked no more.Then, the page displays "text2".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In answer to your second problem, you can set a short timeout to change the link:

```
check.onblur = function() {
    setTimeout( function() {
        testElement.innerHTML = text2.link("home.php");
    }, 250);
}
```

The code calls an anonymous function after 250ms that will return the link to the "blur" link.  It should give the user enough time for the link's click event to register.  You can change 250 to suit your needs after testing.